# How can I connect mongodb with reactjs?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, sass, reactive-programming

I want to connect mongoDb with react.

My need is: I have to store my sass variable in mongoDb and than fetch them in my sass via mongoDb.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You, unfortunately, can't

This is the standard setup for web applications

frontend --> backend --> db

With your current setup its:

frontend --> db

You must have a backend to access the db

## ----------------------------------

React being our frontend, you must have a backend if you would like to use MongoDB

Ruby on Rails, Django, Meteor.js, Express.js, Golang Gin, etc